# Do IIS/CLR start new instance-object for all concurrent calls to .NET Web Service?

Tags: .net, web-services

Does anyone know how IIS/.NET web services handle call-concurrency?

I can think of two tactics:

1. Create an instance. Let all clients call the WebMethod:s from their own calling-thread. Instance-object needs to be thread-safe.
2. Create an instance per calling client.

(Does having Sessions enabled change the behaviour?)

(Note. Not using WCF.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An instance of your `[WebService]` class is created for each request.  Only the one request will ever access that instance.

Answer (score 1):

A web service is an HttpApplication just like an ASPX website, so IIS will maintain an app pool. One app, AFAIK, services one Session, so think of it as instance-per-caller but with some slack so new callers aren't kept waiting.